How can I remove the red part of the svg so that whatever behind it is showing?
How can I remove the red part of the svg kinda like how when you remove the background of an image for example the file turns into a png and the part you removed shows the checkered pattern.
After removing the red part, the orange color from the section should be showing.


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: orange;
}
<section>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" fill="#FF0000">
    <rect fill="#FFF" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 77 666.7 77 833.3 28 1000 28V0H0Z" opacity=".5"></path>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 70 666.7 70 833.3 16 1000 16V0H0Z" opacity=".5"></path>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 63 666.7 63 833.3 4 1000 4V0H0Z"></path>
  </svg>
</section>




The red area is an important element, not a background. The representation is not accurate. But I posted it in the answer because I can meet the conditions you mentioned.

I know that you got a lot of answers for you question, but instead of asking how you remove the red color, it would be a good idea to share what the goal is. What is it that you would like to achieve?

Try changing the fill of rect.
You may think about using CSS filter, but there are many difficulties because the elements that can be controlled are red.
I hope it helps :)
Method1
A new svg image
I worked with illustration and photoshop and saved it as an svg file.
So, you can get white elemnt, transparent background



* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: orange;
}
<section>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1000.9 96.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000.9 96.4;"
    xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0{opacity:0.5;fill:#FFFFFF;}
      .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    </style>
    <switch>
      <foreignObject requiredExtensions="&ns_ai;" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
        <i:aipgfRef  xlink:href="#adobe_illustrator_pgf">
        </i:aipgfRef>
      </foreignObject>
      <g i:extraneous="self">
        <path class="st0" d="M1000.9,0.3v96.2H0c0,0,78.3,2.1,163.7-31.9s159.4-41.9,265.7-29.9c100.7,11.4,139.9,29.1,252.5,23.8
          c121.2-5.6,139-28,194.4-43.1C944.8-3.3,1000.9,0.3,1000.9,0.3z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M1000.9,12.5v83.9H0c0,0,78.3,2.1,163.7-31.9s169.4-45.1,265.7-28.4c96.9,16.8,139.9,33,252.5,29.5
          c121.2-3.7,138.4-27.2,194.4-40C944.3,10.1,1000.9,12.5,1000.9,12.5z"/>
        <path class="st1" d="M1000.9,24.5v71.9H0c0,0,78.3,2.1,163.7-31.9s165.5-44.5,261.7-27.8c96.9,16.8,143.5,38.5,256.1,35
          c121.2-3.7,125.2-20.7,195.3-35.6C945.1,21.7,1000.9,24.5,1000.9,24.5z"/>
      </g>
    </switch>
</section>



Method2
Red path to orange
The svg currently has the part represented in red as an object. It's hard to change it to transparent. You can match it with the background color.


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: orange;
}
<section>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" fill="orange">
    <rect fill="#fff" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 77 666.7 77 833.3 28 1000 28V0H0Z" opacity=".5"></path>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 70 666.7 70 833.3 16 1000 16V0H0Z" opacity=".5"></path>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 63 666.7 63 833.3 4 1000 4V0H0Z"></path>
  </svg>
</section>



Remove white background
Method1


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: orange;
}
<section>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" fill="#FF0000">
    <rect fill="transparent" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 77 666.7 77 833.3 28 1000 28V0H0Z" opacity=".5"></path>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 70 666.7 70 833.3 16 1000 16V0H0Z" opacity=".5"></path>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 63 666.7 63 833.3 4 1000 4V0H0Z"></path>
  </svg>
</section>



Method2
There is also a way to set transparency.
For example, I adjusted it moderately.


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: orange;
}
<section>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" fill="#FF0000">
    <rect fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0.2" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 77 666.7 77 833.3 28 1000 28V0H0Z" opacity=".5"></path>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 70 666.7 70 833.3 16 1000 16V0H0Z" opacity=".5"></path>
    <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 63 666.7 63 833.3 4 1000 4V0H0Z"></path>
  </svg>
</section>




sorry I did not explain it well. I was looking to remove the red part of the svg so the red part is transparent/removed like when you remove the background of an image not transparent as in the color transparent

That svg has red object and white background. if it's the other way around.. we'll have to deal with svg with object that is white..

 <section>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" view Box="0 0 1000 100">
        <react fill="#FFF" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 77 666.7 77 833.3 28 1000 28V0H0Z" opacity=".5"></path>
        <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 70 666.7 70 833.3 16 1000 16V0H0Z" opacity=".5"></path>
        <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 63 666.7 63 833.3 4 1000 4V0H0Z" fill="none"></path>
    </svg>
</section>


Pardon me, but this neither explains or illustrates a working approach.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

For multiple levels of transparency you need a <mask>.
Transparency can either be defined by opacity values or by the grayscale value of a color (actually, how photoshop masks work):

100% white = fully opaque
50% black = semi transparent
100% black = fully transparent



* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: orange;
}
<section>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100">
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask">
        <rect fill="#FFF" width="100%" height="100%" />
        <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 77 666.7 77 833.3 28 1000 28V0H0Z" fill-opacity=".5"></path>
        <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 70 666.7 70 833.3 16 1000 16V0H0Z" fill-opacity=".5"></path>
        <path d="M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 63 666.7 63 833.3 4 1000 4V0H0Z"></path>
      </mask>
    </defs>

    <!-- apply mask -->
    <rect mask="url(#mask)" fill="#FFF" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </svg>
</section>



You may also define the mask as a data URL in CSS – in this case you may probably reverse the masking to show the back ground color of a <div>


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: orange;
}

.masked {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1000 100'><rect fill='white' width='100%' height='100%'/><path d='M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 77 666.7 77 833.3 28 1000 28V0H0Z' fill-opacity='.5'/><path d='M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 70 666.7 70 833.3 16 1000 16V0H0Z' fill-opacity='.5'/><path d='M0 0v100c166.7 0 166.7-66 333.3-66S500 63 666.7 63 833.3 4 1000 4V0H0Z'/></svg>");
  mask-mode: luminance;
  mask-size: contain;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<div class="masked"></div>



Masks vs. clip-paths
Although both concepts serve a similar purpose they have different limitations and behaviors:
Masks

"8bit" alpha transparency – support multiple grades of transparency
support for strokes and dashed strokes
easier to use with regards to responsive layouts (e.g due to mask-size properties
don't affect the hit area for pointer events (the invisible/transparent areas still respond to pointer events unlike clipped areas)
put more load on the renderer as they introduce a rgba rendering context

Clip-paths

"1bit" transparency: areas are either fully opaque (within the clip-path element) or fully transparent/invisible (everthing outside the clip-path)
strokes are ignored
more refactoring needed for responsive clip-paths (e.g by scaling and setting and clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox". See "Complex SVG clip-path responsive"
"cut-out" the hit area – invisible areas won't respont to pointer events
more performant

If you definitely need semi-transparencies – masks are the way to go.
If you only need to "cut-out" a shape you should take the slightly more sturdy way and opt for clip-paths.
If you only need polygonal clipping – CSS clip-paths are probably the best option – due to their support for relative units in polygon definitions.

Oh, I think this is the best way. I learned a lot. Thank you!

@NINE: thanks! to be honest: the current state of masks/clip-path implementations can be quite confusing and frustrating (especially in terms of responsiveness) - I think I've never achieved the desired result at the first shot (despite "shooting" for quite some time;)
